# Traveling from Kyiv(Ukraine) to Helsinki via Amsterdam with visa issued by The Netherlands

Tags: schengen, ukraine, finland, schengen-visas

I have a visa issued by the Netherlands(multi, type C) and I would like to travel to Helsinki. I have never entered the Netherlands by the mentioned visa. There is a flight available through Amsterdam, so technically I will enter the Netherlands first. However, this is just transit. Can I do this way, and is there any potential problems?

p.s I am considering obtaining Finnish visa, however, there is no timeslots available yet, I may not make it because the trip is soon.
p.p.s. I have applied for a biometrical passport, however, it will not be on time.

Comment: When you applied for the Netherlands visa, you presumably described your travel plans, and they should have involved the Netherlands in a significant way.  What's the reason for the change?

Comment: It was a business trip that unfortunately did not happen. But the visa remained, afaik was not terminated

Answer (score 1):

If your Visa will not expire during this trip you can do next:
- there is 95% probability that the border officer will not ask any additional questions.
- if they ask something you can tell that you are planning a future trip to Netherlands with this Visa.

According to the rules you are not obliged to make the first trip to the country which has issued the visa. But to follow the rules you have to make the trip to the country which has issued the visa.